# How to define swift version of spec.dependency "xxx", "~> 1.0" in podspec file

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am write a Cocoapod library, and I am using some dependencies.

Is it possible to specify the build version of Swift for a specific dependency?

Example:

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
spec.name = "xxx"
spec.version = "0.0.1"
spec.swift_version = 5.0
...

spec.dependency "Alamofire", "~> 5.0"
spec.dependency "AnotherPod", "~> 1.1"
end
```

My package will be compiled with Swift 5, but my AnotherPod dependency needs to be compiled in Swift 4.2

I`m use Cocoapod 1.9.1

Answer (score 0):

According to [this document](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/cocoapods/0.3.0/Pod%2FPodfile:dependency), there is no way to restrict dependencies to the certain `swift_version`.

You can monitor the dependency repositories when they change the swift version to the one that you don't support, let's say, in the version of Alamofire `5.1` they've upgraded `swift_version`, while you don't, - then you can limit the upper and lower allowed versions of your dependencies, like

```
spec.dependency "Alamofire", ['>= 5.0', '< 5.1']
```

You can refer to [this document](https://guides.rubygems.org/patterns/) for advanced syntax of version limitation of dependencies.